# Tool tip not working on text area bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 3 form on which i apply tootip via script. the toottip is working fine on input box but not working on textarea.

```
<div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="firstname">Message Subject : </label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Subject" id="name" name="Subject" maxlength="70" minlength="10" required
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter subject" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Input Message Subject between 10 to 80" />
              <p class="help-block"></p>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="control-label" for="content" >Message Content : </label>
              <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control"
              placeholder="Message" id="message" name="Content" required
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" minlength="5"
              data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters"
              maxlength="999" style="resize:none" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Input Message Subject between 50 to 500"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and the script goes like this

```
 $('a').tooltip({placement: "top"});

    $('input[type=text][name=Subject]').tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "focus"
});

$('input[type=textarea][name=Content]').tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "focus"
});
```

It is working well on input text but not on textarea..

Comment: Whats the exact issue? seems to be working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ky6emjxz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is wrong change it to this:

```
$('textarea[name=Content]')
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ky6emjxz/1/)